# WSDL generation behind load balancer

Tags: java, jax-ws, load-balancing, oc4j

I have the following issue with my JAX-WS Ri webservice:

Let's say an external user wants to connect to the webservice with an url. During the request (which passes through a load-balancer and has SSL-offloading), the service is accessed on a OC4J container, which generates a WSDL that returns to the client. However, the returning WSDL contains URLs that contain the name of the internal machine instead of the external url. This results in a scenario where other programs cannot link to our WSDL, as they cannot fully download it (see drawing for clarification).

[image]

How can I make the WSDL accessible for external users? (i.e. trick the service into generating url's using the externalurl.com reference, rather than its machine name?)

For what it's worth: In Tomcat you can specify proxyName and proxyPort for a Connector. How can this be achieved in OC4J?

Answer (score 0):

You can provide an oracle-webservices.xml file along with your application to override the default binding settings of the OC4J container.

You can find more information [here](https://docs.oracle.com/html/E13982_01/apporawebsrvc.htm).